# ISO Date format from MongoDB with jQuery

Tags: jquery, mongodb

I need to retrieve an ISO date from Mongodb using Jquery.

Example Mongodb ISO date: `2013-12-28T08:30:17.795Z`

Target: `28-12-2013 8:30:17`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your format absolutely, I think you have to concatenate elements by yourself or invoke something with identical effect.

```
var date = new Date("2013-12-28T08:30:17.795Z");

// from your output, it seems that you want to get UTC time
var result = date.getUTCDate() + "-" + (date.getUTCMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getUTCFullYear() 
    + " " + date.getUTCHours() + ":" + date.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + date.getUTCSeconds();

// if you want to get locale time, use
var result = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear() 
    + " " + date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a new date in jquery and pass in the ISODate as a string:

```
var d = new Date("2013-12-28T08:30:17.795Z");
alert(d.toLocaleString());
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/comerford/pvsc3yLk/